# DNN-display list of products

Tags: content-management-system, dotnetnuke, skin, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-5

I am new to `DotNetNuke` and I have struck in listing products in a module. I did extensive research but was unable to find an answer.

> Below, Here is what I have done with `DotNetNuke`.

I have created page and panes successfully in `DotNetNuke` and I need to display a list of products in a pane dynamically with pagination using `DotNetNuke`.

Here is the demo image depicting how I want to display the products [Click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QaSH.png).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create a module that allows you to manage the products and also display them.

If you look around for the "Task Manager" module example, that might help. 
http://www.dnnsoftware.com/community/learn/video-library/view-video/video/260/view/details/task-manager-part-1-series-introduction

I mention this one because of the 25 part video series that describes it.

Note that while this is an older tutorial, it is still quite valid.

If you go to http://www.dnnsoftware.com/community/participate/module-contest/community-choice-awards, you will find a collection of more modern modules and you may find one that is similar enough to your application that you might start there.  Look at Ralph Williams module as an example.

Also, I recommend Chris Hammonds module development templates.  They will provide lots of scaffolding on which to build your module.